# predict() "appears" to render two different subsets as the same exact values

Tags: r, lm, predict

I am in the process of self-educating myself in R, and attempting to use the predict() for the first time. My objective is creating a linear model of two predicted vectors: "yC.hat", and "yT.hat".

**Issue (elaborated)**: I feel certain that there is nothing wrong with the way I've written the regression. It contains a numeric vector which is an index and a dummy variable (0,1) representing the control and treatment groups, respectively. And so, I attempt predict outcomes of index values under both dummy variable conditions and store each as a vector. What I get instead from both are two vectors which equals the length of my original data frame (sample) and have identical values. I've tried playing around with the formula for several hours, but anything I do seems to be further off the mark than my first attempt.

**Approximate reproduction of original problem code:**

```
index <- runif(417, min = 9, max = 25)
outcome <- runif(417, min = 15, max = 100)
sample <- data.frame(index,outcome)
#create dummy variables
sample$dummy <- ifelse(sample$index > 13, 1, 0)

fit <- lm(sample$outcome ~ sample$index + sample$dummy)

## predicted outcome under the treatment condition
yT.hat <- predict(fit,
newdata = data.frame(index = 9:25, dummy = 1))

## predicted outcome under the control condition
yC.hat <- predict(fit,
newdata = data.frame(index = 9:25, dummy = 0))
```

Output:

```
> ## predicted turnout rate under the Treatment condition
> yT.hat <- predict(fit,
+ newdata = data.frame(index = 9:25, dummy = 1))
Warning: 'newdata' had 17 rows but variables found have 417 rows
> ## predicted turnout rate under the Control condition
> yC.hat <- predict(fit,
+ newdata = data.frame(index = 9:25, dummy = 0))
Warning: 'newdata' had 17 rows but variables found have 417 rows
```

Meanwhile, both yT.hat and yC.hat return the same values.

Answer (score 1):

It is just that the `call` predictors are not matching.  We may construct the formula as

```
fit <- lm(outcome ~ index + dummy, data = sample)
```

Now we test

```
> yT.hat <- predict(fit,
+ newdata = data.frame(index = 9:25, dummy = 1))
> yC.hat <- predict(fit,
+ newdata = data.frame(index = 9:25, dummy = 0))
```

No warnings

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. I've been running lm() just fine until now. The issues don't appear until I actually use predict(). EDIT: just noticed your edited comment, putting it to test

Comment: @professor.luther.ratigan it needs matching column names, here the `sample$` is also added as per the formula.  ie. you can check `attr(terms(fit), "factors")` from your code and mine

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This worked for the example data, but I'm continuing to have the same central issue. I've rephrased my question here (Again, I fully appreciate your feedback provided thus far): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72770077/inputs-of-2-separate-predict-return-the-same-set-of-fitted-values