# inputs of 2 separate predict() return the same set of fitted values

Tags: r, linear-regression, predict

Confession: I attempted to ask this question yesterday, but used a sample, congruent dataset which resembles the my "real" data in hopes this would be more convenient for readers here. One issue was resolved, but another remains that appears immutable.

My objective is creating a linear model of two predicted vectors: "yC.hat", and "yT.hat" which are meant to project average effects for unique observed values of pri2000v as a function of the average poverty level "I(avgpoverty^2) under control (treatment = 0) and treatment (treatment = 1) conditions.

While I appear to have no issues running the regression itself, the inputs of my data argument have no effect on predict(), and only the object itself affects the output. As a result, treatment = 0 and treatment = 1 in the data argument result in the same fitted values. In fact, I can plug in ANY value into the data argument and it makes do difference. So I suspect my failure to understand issue starts here.

Here is my code:

```
q6rega <- lm(pri2000v ~ treatment + I(log(pobtot1994)) + I(avgpoverty^2)
   #interactions
   + treatment:avgpoverty + treatment:I(avgpoverty^2), data = pga)

## predicted PRI support under the Treatment condition
q6.yT.hat <- predict(q6rega,
data = data.frame(I(avgpoverty^2) = 9:25, treatment = 1))
## predicted PRI support rate under the Control condition
q6.yC.hat <- predict(q6rega,
data = data.frame(I(avgpoverty^2) = 9:25, treatment = 0))

q6.yC.hat == q6.yT.hat

TRUE[417]
```

**[dput(pga](https://github.com/professor-luther-ratigan/rselfstudy/issues/1) has been posted on my github, if needed**

EDIT: There were a few things wrong with my code above, but not specifying pobtot1994 somehow resulted in R treating it as newdata being omitted. Since I'm fairly new to statistics, I confused fitted values with the prediction output that I was actually trying to achieve. I would have expected that an unexpected input is to produce an error instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised  you are able to run a prediction when it is lacking the required variable (`pobtot1994`) for your model in the new data frame for prediction.

Anyway, you would need to create a new data frame with the three variables in untransformed form used in the model. Since you are interested to compare the fitted values of `avgpoverty` 3 to 5 for `treatment` 1 and 0, you need to force the third variable `pobtot1994` as a constant. I use the mean of `pobtot9994` here for simplicity.

```
newdat <- expand.grid(avgpoverty=3:5, treatment=factor(c(0,1)), pobtot1994=mean(pga$pobtot1994))

  avgpoverty treatment pobtot1994
1          3         0   2037.384
2          4         0   2037.384
3          5         0   2037.384
4          3         1   2037.384
5          4         1   2037.384
6          5         1   2037.384
```

The prediction will show you the different values for the two conditions.

```
newdat$fitted <- predict(q6rega, newdata=newdat)

  avgpoverty treatment pobtot1994   fitted
1          3         0   2037.384 38.86817
2          4         0   2037.384 50.77476
3          5         0   2037.384 55.67832
4          3         1   2037.384 51.55077
5          4         1   2037.384 49.03148
6          5         1   2037.384 59.73910
```